# Is it possible to pipe vim commands to vim?

Tags: invocation

I want to run the following shell.

```
wea-this is the end of the second word | vim j
exit 0
```

Which I had hoped would pipe the key strokes `w` (move forward a word) then `e` (end of the word) then `a` (append) then `-this is the end of the second word` (text) to the Vim document named `j` which already has words in it.

The following error occurred when I ran the shell script.

```
/root/bin/tt.sh: line 1: wea-this: command not found
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.
Two types of answers will be appreciated:

1. How to use piping to achieve this desired result.
2. Another method by which I can use "Vim commands" (not ed or sed commands) to edit a text document from a shell script.

Comment: The `|` character pipes the output of one command to another. `wea-this` is not a command. Piping cannot be used to achieve what you're looking to do either; it'll cause Vim's stdin to be the left hand application, not the keyboard. If you want to get stdin into a buffer in vim, start it with a minus for the filename: `echo Hello, world! | vim -`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To insert the string `"hello"` on the first line of the file `j`, you could type in your shell the following command:

`vim +"1 | put! ='hello'" j`

- `:1` moves the cursor to the first line of the buffer
- `:put! ='hello'` pastes the string "hello" above the current line

To insert the string `"hello"` and then save and quit the file:

`vim +"1 | put! ='hello' | x" j`

Same thing as before, we've just added the Ex command `:x` which saves and quit.

More generally you can execute any sequence of Ex commands on a file, from an interactive shell or from a bash script, like this:

`vim +'Ex command1 | Ex command2 | ...' file`

If you have a lot of Ex commands, you could write them all inside a dedicated file (called for example `myExCommands.vim`), one command per line, and then from the shell or a script you could source it (with the Ex command `:source` or the short version`:so`) like this:

```
vim +'so myExCommands.vim' file
```

**Edit**

I see you've edited your question.
I think the previous answer still applies, because you can execute any normal command from Ex mode with the Ex commands `:normal` and `:execute`.

For example, let's say you want to :

- move your cursor on the first line of the buffer (`1G`)
- move your cursor to the first non whitespace character on the line (`_`)
- move your cursor one word forward (`w`)
- move your cursor to the end of the new word (`e`)
- go into insert mode after the character under the cursor (`a`)
- insert the string `hello`
- save and quit (`:x`)

To do this on the file `j`, type from the shell:

```
vim +"execute 'normal! 1G_weahello' | x" j
```

For more information, see:

```
:help +cmd
:help :normal
:help :execute
```

Comment: I failed to fully clarify my goal. I want to be able to use vims commands, such as w to move forward a word and such. I will edit my question to correct.

Comment: @JasonBasanese I've edited my answer, do the Ex commands `:normal` and `:execute` do what you want?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a way you can use normal-mode commands, rather than just ex commands, to edit a stream presented to Vim from stdin. This isn't a very useful example, but it illustrates the techniques involved. It assumes that your shell is bash.

```
echo "The brown fox jumped." | vim -s <(printf 'wcwred\e:wq! foo\n') -
```

The `-` at the end tells Vim to read text (not commands) from stdin. The `-s` tells Vim to execute keystrokes from the specified file. In this case, the file is the output of a bash process substitution. The `<(...)` is replaced by the name of a named pipe. The output of the pipe is the output of the command within the parentheses. The `wcwred\e` moves the cursor by one word and changes that next word to `red`. The `:wq! foo\n` saves the result to the file `foo` even if that file already exists. The end result is a file named `foo` containing the text `The red fox jumped.`

For more on some of those topics, see

```
:help -file
:help -s
```

See also the `Process Substitution` section of the `bash(1)` man page.

Comment: Added to my ~/.zshrc: `vimx () { vi -s <(echo "$1"':wq') "$2" &> /dev/null; }`. Now I can `vimx 'iThe brow fox jumped.\e' foo; vimx 'wcwred\efjdwiclimbed\e' foo; cat foo`. Neat!

Comment: @LeonardPauli: Looks useful! Is the error output not usable? Why is it `/dev/null`ed?

Comment: Resource links:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution

Answer (score 5):

I have found the method of taking the output of a program as redirected from sub-shell to be very easy:

```
vim <( program )
```

Example:

```
 vim <( grep -nH  hello  myFile.cpp )
 vim <( find . -name '*.cpp' -exec grep -nH code_expr {} \+ )
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same desire as you: I wanted to write normal vim commands and have those edit a pipeline stream. I was disappointed by the difficulty of using normal vim in this way (so many flags!), as provided by the default vim options.

Therefore, I wrote a small wrapper on vim to do it: https://github.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream/. It's called `vims`.

The heart of the wrapper is the following command:

```
vim - -nes "${vim_cmds[@]}" -c ':q!' | tail -n +2
```

Using this, with the command generation I do, it works out to be quite concise, and because vim is a modal editor, I made `vims` a modal stream editor. There are three main modes which are useful for with pipeline-editing mentality:

```
[-t|--turn-off-mode] - (Default mode)
                       Every string is a vim command line, e.g., '%g/foo/d' deletes
                       all lines with foo.
[-e|--exe-mode] -      Translated to '%g/$1/exe "norm $2"', see examples below
[-s|--simple-mode] -   Like exe-mode, but runs on 1st line only
```

Watch this:

```
$ echo "Hello World" | vims -s "ea Beautiful"
Hello Beautiful World
```

So, `e` goes to the end of `Hello`, then `a` starts appending.

Something fancier, in exe-mode, to comment out lines containing `my_bad_var`, and delete the preceding line.

```
cat my_script.cpp | vims -e 'my_bad_var' 'I//\<esc>kdd'
```

Which translates to `vims '%g/my_bad_var/exe "norm I//\<esc>kdd"'` - the `I` being the command
to start insert at the start of the line, and `//` being the comment sequence.
`\<esc>kdd` pushes the escape key, moves up a line, then deletes the line.

I have 11 total examples on the repo, I encourage you to check them out. Again, this is running on top of vim, it's just a way to make vim more like sed for stream input (but preserving all your beloved vim macros!)

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly old question, but I felt that it was worth contributing that if your given distro/OS has access to [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), then you can install it and simply use `vipe` as a standard addition to `vim`:

```
echo foo | vipe # Now you can edit "foo" to be "bar"!
```

`moreutils` is super handy for its other tools, too, and I'd highly recommend them if you're a serious command-line user! :) Take a look at the author's introduction (previous link) for more details.

[`moreutils` should be generally available to most *nix-like distros via a package manager and via Homebrew on Mac](https://rentes.github.io/unix/utilities/2015/07/27/moreutils-package/#installing). For example...

```
# Arch Linux and MSYS2 (more below) as part of the `community` repo
pacman -Sy moreutils


# Mac OS and Homebrew
brew install moreutils
```

`moreutils` is also a [part of the MSYS2 package repository](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/moreutils), so you can technically use it on Windows too. :)