# Using the ex mode command line (-c), how would I insert text?

Tags: ex-mode, invocation

I am interested in mastering the art of using `ex` from the command line (`vi -esc <commands>` / `ex -sc <commands>`). I got [the basics](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/how-to-use-c-command-line-option) worked out, but one thing eludes me:

**How do I add text using insert mode?**

Let's say I want to add text at the end of the file. In interactive ex, I would do:

```
$ ex file.txt
:normal! G
$a
foo
.
x
```

But if I enter that same sequence as `-c` command line option when invoking `ex`, I get stuck on the interactive `ex` command line, and if I enter `x` from there, my file remains unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `-s` in Ex mode `:help -s-ex` states:

> To be used when Vim is used to execute Ex commands from a file instead of a terminal.

So it seems the correct approach is to save your commands into a file and then run:

```
vim -es < commands.ex file.txt
```

N.B. Note that you don't *need* to use the Ex mode `-e` argument to run Vim commands non-interactively: the commands you add with `-c` are already interpreted as Ex commands, and you can have up to 10 of them (see `:help -c`), so you could also do something like:

```
vim -c "normal! G" -c "normal! ofoo" -c x file.txt
```

Or more concisely:

```
vim "+norm! Gofoo" +x file.txt
```

Comment: I don't really like the idea of going through external temporary files. Otherwise, thanks for the hint to split up the command string into multiple `-c` options.

Comment: @DevSolar In that case, [see also garyjohn's answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5994/343) for one method of using a shell feature to avoid having to create a temporary file (and possibly the other answers on that page.